# Apply a comparison symbol from a user input

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```py
     def segment_table(df, col_condition): 
       segment = 
       df[df.loc[:,col_symbol_condition[0]].apply(eval(col_condition[1]))
       return segment
     print(segment_table(example_df, ["columns", "<4"])
```

But it does not work. How can I apply a <, > and so on operator in such a situation? Thanks

Comment: Could you post an reproductible example with an expected output ?

Comment: Expected outcome of the code above is a table which contains the instances where the column "columns" is less than 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply this function to each row of your `DataFrame`:

```
def evaluate(row, column, condition):
    if eval(str(row[column])+condition[0]+condition[1:]):
        return row
    return

example_df.apply(evaluate, args=("columns","<4"), axis=1).dropna()
```

It will return the rows that satisfy the condition specified in the "condition" argument, on the column specifies in the "column" argument.
It will only work for '<' and '>' operators, since they are only one character long.

Here is the result on a very simple DataFrame:

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],
                           [6, 7],
                           [3, 4]], columns=['col1', 'columns'])
```

Output:

```
    col1    columns
0   1.0     2.0
```

Comment: I want the comparison operator to be dynamic, for the user to input it as a function argument. I have figured out how to make the 4 in your example dynamic, but what I cannot figure out is how to make the comparison operator dynamic.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understood your question ! I updated my answer.